# python pandas native select_as_multiple

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

Suppose I have a DataFrame that is block sparse. By this I mean that there are groups of rows that have disjoint sets of non-null columns. Storing this a huge table will use more memory in the values (nan filling) and unstacking the table to rows will creating a large index (at least it appears that way on saving to disk ... I'm not 100% clear if there is some efficient MultiIndexing that is supposed to be going on).

Typically, I store the blocks as separate DataFrames in a dict or list (dropping the nan columns) and make a class that has almost the same api as a DataFrame, 'manually' passing the queries to the blocks and concatenating the results. This works well but involves a short amount of some special code to store and handle these objects.

Recently, I've noticed that pytables provides a feature similar to this but only for the pytables query api.

*Is there some way of handling this natively in pandas? Or am I missing some simpler way of getting a solution that is similar in performance?*

EDIT: Here is a small example dataset

```
import pandas, string, itertools
from pylab import *

# create some data and put it in a list of blocks (d)
m = 10; n = 6;
s = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
A = array([s[x] * (1 + mod(x, 3)) for x in randint(0, 26, m*n)]).reshape(m, n)
df = pandas.DataFrame(A)
d = list()
d += [df.ix[0:(m/2)].T.ix[0:(n/2)].T]
d += [df.ix[(m/2):].T.ix[(n/2):].T]

# 1. use lots of memory, fill with na
d0 = pandas.concat(d) # this is just the original df

# 2. maybe ok, not sure how this is handled across different pandas versions
d1 = pandas.concat([x.unstack() for x in d])

# want this to work however the blocks are stored
print(d0.ix[[0, 8]][[2,5]])

# this raises exception
sdf = pandas.SparseDataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Can you post some example data demonstrating the kind of structure you're dealing with? Also, if you've looked at `pandas.SparseDataFrame`, can you explain why that doesn't work for your case?

Comment: @Marius: Thanks, I wasn't really aware of SparseDataFrame. Had a brief look and a brief try with it and it appears to only handle floats (at least by default). The use-case I'm thinking of involves mixed types, I may be able to enforce some stricter typing at a column-by-column level if I do some work.

Comment: in 0.13, sparse will support multi-dtypes, so that may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `HDFStore` this way

- Store different tables with a common index (that is itself) a column
- only the non-all-nan rows would be stored. so if you group your columns intelligently (e.g.
  put the ones that would tend to have lots of sparseness in the same place together). I think you could achieve a 'sparse'-like layout.
- you can compress the table if necessary.
- you can then query individual tables, and get the coordinates to then pull from other tables (this is what select_as_multiple does).

Can you provde a small example, and rough size of data set, e.g. num of rows, columuns, disjoint groups, etc.

What do your queries look like? This is generally how I approach the problem. Figure our how you are going to query; this is going to define how you store the data layout.

Comment: Yes, HDFStore is what I mean by select_as_multiple. I think I could set this up with most of the blocks not having the full indexed set. But what I think I really want is the pandas api. i.e. I want to be able to type df.ix[something] and get a fast response at the prompt. 

The data I'm thinking of for this use case fits in memory, with say about 50 blocks mostly in the thousands of rows. Unstacking to a MultiIndex of (Index, ColumnName) -> value works too but somehow doesn't feel as nice since the return structure would typically need to be pivoted back to index vs column view.

Comment: ok...if this can be done in memory, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: The issue is the pandas api ... I want 50 dataframes to behave as one. Merging the frames *can not* be done in memory. Working with a MultiIndex Series (ID, attribute) -> value does not work as well (selecting at the second level is a pain).

Comment: you are welcome to contribute this this discussion: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3443, but without an example still not clear what you are doing.